# ASP.NET page lifecycle sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I have user control on my page, then what will be sequence of loading.

Does page or user control events will get loaded first?

Also I am quite confused about how page lifecycle works in ASP.NET? Is there any simplest explanation for that? Also do let me know if there is any ASP.NET quick concept revising online resource.

Comment: saa msdn about [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Go to asp.net website, that should help you get started.

Comment: @Pritam - Controls are "loaded" in the order they appear on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just made an extract ::

## PreInit

Raised after the start stage is complete and before the initialization stage begins.

Use this for

- Check IsPostback, IsCallback and IsCrossPagePostBack properties.
- Create or recreate dynamic controls.
- Set a master page dynamically.
- Set the Theme property dynamically.
- Read or set profile property values.

Don't use

- If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet been restored from view state.
- If you set a control property at this stage, its value might be overwritten in the next event.

## Init

Raised after all controls have been initialized and any skin settings have been applied.

Use this for

- The Init event of individual controls occurs before the Init event of the page.
- Use this event to read or initialize control properties.

## InitComplete

Raised at the end of the page's initialization stage.Here tracking of view state changes is turned on.

Use this for

- Use this event to make changes to view state that you want to make sure are persisted after the next postback.

## PreLoad

Raised after the page loads view state for itself and all controls.

## Load

The Load event of individual controls occurs after the Load event of the page.

Use this for

- Use the OnLoad event method to set properties in controls and to establish database connections.

## Control Event

Use these events to handle specific control events.

## LoadComplete

Raised at the end of the event-handling stage.

Use this for

- Use this event for tasks that require that all other controls on the page be loaded.

## PreRender

The PreRender event of individual controls occurs after the PreRender event of the page.

Use this for
 - Use the event to make final changes to the contents of the page or its controls before the rendering stage begins.

## PreRenderComplete

Raised after each data bound control whose DataSourceID property is set calls its DataBind method.

## SaveStateComplete

Raised after view state and control state have been saved for the page and for all controls.

## Render

Rendering of page and controls happen here.

## Unload

Raised for each control and then for the page.

Use this for

- To do final clean-up such as closing open files and database connections, or finishing up logging.

Here is resource source.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: An extract is not really good enough.  As you can see I've edited your answer to make it readable using markup.  You should also add a link to where you got the material.